# Is there a use case where tasks perform worse than threads?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

It is considered that tasks are usually better choice than threads as they avoid wasting OS threads and give more programmatic control, but I wonder is there actually a use case where tasks performs worse than threads (so threads should be used instead)?

Comment: Tasks [may] *use* Threads.. the beauty of Tasks is they separate the concept and implementation and take care of the details, including Threading Pools.

Comment: @user2864740 Tasks *may* use threads...

Comment: This is like asking why Apples are worse than Apple flavored hard candies.

Comment: Tasks are built using threads as lower level primitives, so Tasks are always slower compared to correct usage of underlying lower level primitives like threads, async IO and other functionality commonly *used* by tasks... But you probably asking about something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A task, when is about to be executed, will be executed in a thread context. A thread from the .NET thread pool will be used for the execution of a task. That being said there isn't any comparison between them.

Specifically, a task will be assigned to a thread of the thread pool to be executed, provided that there is a free thread. If there isn't any available thread, then the task will be placed in a queue waiting for one of the used threads to be free and it will be assigned to this thread (if the task is the first in the queue...). If the task will wait a long time in the queue (there is a specific time interval for this, but I don't remember it at this moment), then a new thread will be created, in order to service this task.